# Why do the COVID vaccines not cause the body's immune system to over-react?

Tags: covid-19

It was my understanding that the reason why some people suffered serious effects from a COVID19 infection is that their immune system over-reacted to the disease, causing havoc all over.  Why doesn't the vaccine --- which stimulates the creation of COVID19 antibodies --- similarly cause the immune system to over-react in the same way among those who would be susceptible to immunological over-reaction?